# sqlcipher version migration for ios project

Tags: ios, iphone, database, openssl, sqlcipher

I was using older version of `sqlcipher` and `open ssl` for application. Now I migrated to newer version for `Xcode 5` and `iOS 7` compatibility, but it is not decrypting the older version of database.

Please help me out. I searched on google and found that something like `cipher_migrate` has to be used, but not knowing how to use it.

Comment: Me,either. Did you get a workaround since then??

Answer (score -1):

The `PRAGMA cipher_migrate` command can be used to upgrade standard 1.x and 2.x SQLCipher database formats to the 3.x version.  The pragma is to be called following the keying of the database.  The documentation for it can be found [here](http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-api/#cipher_migrate).

Comment: I'd like to know the specific coding sample. All the better for me is with FMDB.